# How exactly std::async is executed?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous

I wonder how does the following code work?

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
struct Task;
std::set<const Task*> dead_tasks;
struct Task
{
   ~Task() { dead_tasks.insert(this); std::cout << "dtor\n";}
   Task() { std::cout << "ctor\n";}
   Task(Task&&) { std::cout << "move-ctor\n";}
   void operator()() const { std::cout << "func()\n"; }
};
int main(){
   std::cout << dead_tasks.size() << '\n';
   std::async(std::launch::async, Task());
   std::cout << dead_tasks.size() << '\n';
}
```

This code prints

> 0
>   ctor
>   move-ctor
>   move-ctor
>   dtor
>   func()
>   dtor
>   dtor
>   3

If we use std::launch::deferred instead of std::launch::async we will get

> 0
>   ctor
>   move-ctor
>   move-ctor
>   dtor
>   dtor
>   dtor
>   3

So in the latter we miss the member function call.  Why?  I can understand the presence of the call to the default constructor and the call to the move constructor.  Task() calls the default constructor, then std::async does a call to the move constructor...  However I missed the idea behind the second call to the move constructor and the call to the member function.  I can think that the second move constructor is called by std::future, can't I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So in the latter we miss the member function call. Why?

Because the call is, well, deferred. It will only start once you actually request for its results, e.g. by calling `get()` on the future (which you didn't):

```
auto fut = std::async(std::launch::deferred, Task());
fut.get();
```

> I can think that the second move constructor is called by std::future,
>   can't I?

This is rather implementation-defined whether and how many calls to a copy-constructor there will be. Building it e.g. in clang gave me even three calls to the move-constructor. Thus, just don't bother about it. But if you do, you have to look into the standard library implementations themselves, if available.

Comment: it shouldn't be deferred. `std::launch::async` specifies that the thread not be deferred.

Comment: @doug Thanks, this was just a copy issue. The argument however still holds.